# android:process=":remote" doesnt prevent separate process from being destroyed with Force Close

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

Im using Sumsung GT-S7710 android version 4.1.2 . When I force close my app from app list in my phone manually - separate service process becomes dead. I can see it in studio. And trully it doesnt work any more (I used to check it with shedulled launching of notification sound). But in many places over the net people say android:process=":remote"  option will prevent my service from being killed, but it seems not working for Force Close case. Any suggestions appreciated. Thx in advance.

```
<service android:name=".ActService" android:process=":remote"/>
```

Comment: "When I force close my app from app list in my phone manually" -- you may wish to explain, in greater detail and perhaps with screenshots, what you mean by this.

Comment: As usual using settings - appliaction manager - there u can force stop your app or uninsall it, or clear cache, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> When I force close my app from app list in my phone manually

What you appear to mean is that you are going to the Settings app, to the Apps screen within there, finding your app, and tapping the "Force Stop" button.

> separate service process becomes dead

Sure. All of your processes will be terminated if the user force-stops the app through Settings.

> But in many places over the net people say android:process=":remote" option will prevent my service from being killed, but it seems not working for Force Close case.

Correct. It is not supposed to work for that case. Where a separate process *may* help is if the user swipes your app's task off of the overview screen (a.k.a., the recent-tasks screen).

Comment: I think maybe native process can help.

Comment: @AlexInspired: I do not know what you mean by a "native process", but if Force Stop does not terminate all of an app's processes, that is a bug that needs to be fixed.